# 403 Forbidden Error with Query String appears once

Tags: javascript, http

I am trying to make a new window page open with javascript arguments passed through into it, hence the `javascript:` in the link.

```
<a href="javascript: window.location='http://www.example.com?title=' +document.title">Link</a>
```

When I click on this link it takes me to the page with the correct query string but it comes up with a 403 Forbidden message. However, if I click the URL at the top and click enter as if I was doing the search myself the 403 Forbidden message disappears and runs as expected.

So my question is: How do I stop the 403 Forbidden message from appearing so it runs as expected?

Thanks.

Comment: Probably thats because the referrer header your browser sends to the server, resulting in a 403 error message

Comment: try this trick that works for html 5 <meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer">

Comment: This is probably due to server do not allow indirect traffic.

Comment: @Cristian Ok I will give it a shot

Comment: @Cristian Hm, I still seem to be getting the issue.

Comment: @TheAkashRajput Do you know if there is anyway around this?

Comment: @NickParsons It depends on which server you are dealing with.

Comment: Another trick would be getting the page serverside then show it as it is hosted on your server

Comment: You'll have to do some http requests in your php

Comment: Here's one for Apache: [Denying referral traffic](http://www.htaccess-guide.com/deny-visitors-by-referrer/)